# When i'm trying to launch application on iphone it's not displaying TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

So I have an application that have a tab in tab bar that display my TableView. Recently I modified it, and change my path for table from default
`NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Food" ofType"plist"];`

replacing it  with this:
`NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject]stringByAppendingString:@"food.plist"];`

So my problem is, it work pretty fine when I am launching it on Simulator in XCode, but, when im trying to launch it on my iphone I cant see any `TableView` appear, just empty search bar and top navigation bar.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject]stringByAppendingString:@"food.plist"];
    listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    searchListOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
    searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    searchBar.delegate = self; 
    [[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:searchBar];

    searching = NO;
    letUserSelectRow = YES;
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addProduct:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}

- (void)hideModalViewController:(NSNotification *)notif {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)addProduct:(UIBarButtonItem *)button {
    BIDAddProductViewController *addProductVC = [[BIDAddProductViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:addProductVC animated:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideModalViewController:) name:@"HideModalViewController" object:addProductVC];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.childController = nil;
    self.tableView = nil;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSLog(@"Delete");
        NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject]stringByAppendingString:@"food.plist"];
        NSMutableArray *listOfItemsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

        [[[listOfItemsToDelete objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"Products"] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [listOfItemsToDelete writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
}
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SectionsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];
    }

    if(searching)
        cell.textLabel.text = [[searchListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"ProductName"];
    else {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
         NSArray *array = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"Products"]valueForKeyPath:@"ProductName"];
        NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (searching)
        return 1;
    else
        return [listOfItems count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (searching)
        return [searchListOfItems count];
    else {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:section];
        NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Products"];
        return [array count];
    }
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(searching)
        return @"";
   return [[listOfItems objectAtIndex:section]valueForKey:@"SectionName"];
}

@end
```

I want to mention that I did some things with Project and Target settings, but, before that issue everything was just fine. I have an iPhone 4s if thats matter. And I did cut lot of my code rows just for make it easier to read (removed searching methods and selecting row methods).

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with -

```
NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject]stringByAppendingString:@"food.plist"];
```

you need to use -

```
NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"food.plist"];
```

Comment: rishi thank you for your help, but when i replaced it i only see blank view, even in simulator.

Comment: @HofthWayer - that's strange!!

Comment: Rishi everything work fine now, you my saver, finally i solve this! But why is it act that way.. Big thanks!

Comment: With stringByAppendingString  you will get something like /Files/Documentsfood.plist while with stringByAppendingPathComponent you will get /Files/Documents/food.plist.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Food" ofType"plist"];
```

searches "Food.plist" (notice the F)

and in

```
NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject]stringByAppendingString:@"food.plist"];
```

you search for "food.plist" (notice low caps f)

Since your device is case sensitive and your Mac by default is not, I suspect that is your problem

Comment: Thanks for tip, but unfortunately when i edit this, it still have same problem :( even when i replay capital "F" for typical "f".

Comment: ok, the other obvious thing I can think of, I just put it here to be sure, is that 'pathForResource' searches your app bundle and I expect that you add Food.plist to your app resources. On the other hand, NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains searches your documents folder and did you put Food.plist in that folder by code? It will not get there by its own. This however does not explain why it runs in your simulator, did you try resetting the simulator and try again?

Comment: Yeah.. many times.. deleting from both simulator and iphone, cleaning, rebooting mac and device :( About capital F, it was just my typing error, since i write code on my PC from my Mac, sorry for this missunderstanding..